# Having trouble solving a 3 marks question

Tags: factoring

Simplify fully:

> $$\frac{3x^2 - 8x - 3} { 2x^2 - 6x}$$

And the answer needs to be $12(x^2 + 1)$

EDIT: Seems like the answer was wrong but I wasn't confident enough to say it. Blaming my teacher for this now. Thank you for the help!

Comment: It's wrong!....

Comment: $\frac {3x^2 - 8x - 3} {2x^2 - 6x} = \frac {(3x+1)(x-3)} {2x(x-3)} =  \frac {3x+1} {2x}, \text {for}\ x \neq 3.$ I don't think any further simplification is possible from here on.

Comment: @Dbchatto67 that's what I got too but the supposed answer is just way different

Comment: The answer is definitely wrong @Nazi Nazzai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{(3x^2 - 8x - 3)}{(2x^2 - 6x)}=\frac{(3x+1)(x-3)}{2x(x-3)}=\frac{3x+1}{2x}$$

I think your answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$3x^2-8x-3=(3x+1)(x-3)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: (Although the answer is wrong).

You can either prove that $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=R(X)$ where $P(x), Q(x)$ and $R(x)$ are polynomials with the [polynomial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) or if you know the answer (as in this case), you might want to prove that $$R(x)·Q(x)=P(x)$$ which is equivalent to $$\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=R(X)$$ whenever $Q(x)≠0.$